# Monad to also measure side effects

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, f#

How can I count the number of times bind is applied on a Monad - Example given a state monad, I'd like to count the number of times state changed. How can i best encapsulate this? Should this logic be part of bind operator (with side effect since it increments count) or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Do you want to count side effects or applications of `bind`? Specifically, should `return () >>= \ () -> ...` count for 0 or 1? And what about `(+) <$> a <*> b`? Should that count as some “binds” or none as it is an applicative operation only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. One of the monad laws is

```
return x >>= f = f x
```

which has one bind on the left and none on the right, so no law-abiding monad can observe how many bindings there are.

At best you may have an action

```
increment :: M ()
```

in your monad which bumps a counter. (This could be implemented, as you say, using `StateT` or similar, or in a couple other essentially isomorphic ways.)

Comment: Perhaps more critically, `w ≡ w>>=return ≡ w>>=return>>=return ≡ ...`.

Comment: I wrote a tracing `Option` a few years ago that recorded where the first `None` came from and it cracked open a few tough bugs.