# Instrumented State monad

Tags: haskell

I am trying to give `Monad` and `MonadState` instances for `State'` that counts the number of `(>>=), return, get` and `put` operations.

```
data Counts = Counts { binds   :: Int
                 , returns :: Int
                 , gets    :: Int
                 , puts    :: Int
                 }

newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }
```

That's what I have already done, and as far as I understand what is going on, this code should work:

```
instance Monad State' where
  return     = State' ( \(s, counts) -> (x, s, counts mappend oneReturn))
  (>>=) st f = State' ( \(s, counts) -> let (x, s', counts') = runState' (s, counts) in runState' ((f x), (s', counts' mappend oneBind)) )

instance Monad m => MonadState m State' where
   get    = State' ( \(s, counts) -> (s, s, counts mappend oneGet) )
   put st = State' ( \(s, counts) -> ((), st, counts mappend onePut) )
```

But I get this error message:

> Expecting one more argument to `‘State'’`
>   Expected kind `‘* -> *’`, but `‘State'’` has kind `‘* -> * -> *’`

Why?

Comment: See also [Monad to also measure side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54281543/791604). In short: you cannot make a law-abiding instance that does what you want. (That is not related to the errors you are getting, though.)

Comment: You should define the instance as `instance Monad (State' s)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you! Now I have 
    "Expecting one more argument to ‘m’
    Expected a type, but ‘m’ has kind ‘* -> *’ "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is in the sentence

`Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘State'’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’`

If you check the kind of `State'` with GHCi using `:k` command you will see that `State'` has kind `* -> * -> *` which simply speaking means that it requires to be parametrized by two types of kind `*` to produce finalized `*` type. `Monad`s are as you see restricted to `* -> *`. For instance `Maybe` is a `Monad`, while `Maybe Int` is not.

To fix your case you will need to apply the state type to `State'` and then you will be able to declare it as a Monad:

```
instance Monad (State' s) where
```

---

The error in the second part is a bit conceptual – what is `m` in your declaration? `MonadState` is a subclass of `Monad`, so every instance of `MonadState` is also instance of `Monad`. With this in mind the correct notation should make some sense:

```
instance MonadState s (State' s) where
```

You don't want to mention this `Monad` – it is derivable from the class declaration.

Comment: If I write like this I am being told to use FlexibleInstances, then MultiParamTypeClasses, and then I get a lot of errors. Do I really need Flexible Instances for this?

Comment: I believe so. `Control.Monad.State.Class` uses these as well (and even more).

Comment: After reminding – you need `MultiParamTypeClasses` for obvious reasons (`MonadState` is such a class). `FlexibleInstances` are required because the `s` type is not in a form "Typeconstructor [arguments]" – which is banned by default and enabled by this extension.