# Function that runs a state monadic computation in the instrumented state monad

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function

```
run :: State' s a -> s -> (a, Counts)
```

that runs a state monadic computation in the instrumented state monad, given some initial state of type s, and returns the computed value and the number of operations counted. For example, this: 
    let tree = Branch (Branch Leaf "B" Leaf) "A" Leaf in  run (label tree) 42
should evaluate to this:
    ( Branch (Branch Leaf (42, "B") Leaf) (43, "A") Leaf, Counts { binds = 10, returns = 5, gets = 4, puts = 2 } )

Here is what I already have:

```
data Counts = Counts { binds   :: Int,
                   returns :: Int,
                   gets    :: Int,
                   puts    :: Int
                 } deriving (Eq, Show)


oneBind   = Counts 1 0 0 0
oneReturn = Counts 0 1 0 0
oneGet    = Counts 0 0 1 0
onePut    = Counts 0 0 0 1


instance Monoid Counts where
  mempty  = Counts 0 0 0 0
  mappend (Counts x1 x2 x3 x4) (Counts y1 y2 y3 y4) = Counts (x1+y1) (x2+y2) (x3+y3) (x4+y4)


instance Semigroup Counts where
  (Counts x1 x2 x3 x4) <> (Counts y1 y2 y3 y4) = Counts (x1+y1) (x2+y2) (x3+y3) (x4+y4)


newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }

instance Monad (State' s) where
  return a   = State' $ \(s, count) -> (a, s, (count <> oneReturn)) 
  (>>=) st f = State' $ \(s, count) -> let (x, s', count') = runState' st (s, count) in runState' (f x) (s', (count' <> oneBind) ) 


instance MonadState s (State' s) where
  get    = State' $ \(s, count) -> (s, s, (count <> oneGet))
  put st = State' $ \(s, count) -> ((), st, (count <> onePut))
```

I have Monad and MonadState instances for State'

I feel like I already have everything that I need to write that run function, but I don't know how to put it all together.

Comment: I think in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762867/instrumented-state-monad) you were told by a comment, that: "See also [Monad to also measure side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281543/monad-to-also-measure-side-effects). In short: you cannot make a law-abiding instance that does what you want. [...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to generate an initial "zero counter", and call `runState'` accordingly, then discard the final state.

```
run :: State' s a -> s -> (a, Counts)
run action st = case runState' action (st, mempty) of
   (x, _st', count) -> (x, count)
```

Note that your monad will not satisfy the monad laws, unless the laws are taken "up to the counters". It can still be a nice exercise to experiment with this, though.